# Riemannian geometry algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is this derivation correct?
$$ R^{ab}_{;a}=0 $$
$$ g_{ac}g_{bd}R^{ab}_{;a}=0 $$
$$ (g_{ac}g_{bd}R^{ab})_{;a}=0 $$
$$ R_{cd;a}=0 $$

And does that mean I now have $n^3$ equation as opposed to $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In the second line, you've incorrectly used the summation convention. The upper $a$ in the first line is a dummy index, already contracted with a lower $a$, so you can't introduce another $a$ into the formula.